# non-greedy regex

Tags: regex

So i have the following...

```
temp = 'item 8 but i want this item 8 and Financial Statements and Supplementary Data'
pattern_8  = r'ITEM 8.*?Financial Statements and Supplementary Data'
```

Then I do...

```
re.search(pattern_8,temp,re.IGNORECASE)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 77), match='item 8 but i want this item 8 and Financial State>
```

But atleats for me it takes the first 'item 8' rather than the second.
I guess I could loop the search over itself until it stops.. but there has to be a reason this non-greedy matching isn't working?

Comment: Consider that the search proceeds from left to right.  Hence it will grab the first match it finds

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're aiming for but as a simple tweak you could get it to skip matching `item` if it's at the beginning of the line with `(?<!^)ITEM 8.*?Financial Statements and Supplementary Data`.  Maybe that's helpful, may it won't answer your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately the text files are complicated and varried so i just need to find the closest item 8 to the phrase. Unfortunately it looks like regex doesn't consider overlapping matches. so I need to find a work around for overlaps

Answer (score 1):

Your result is to be expected. I think you misunderstood what *non-greedy* means. I does *not* mean *»make the whole regex match the shortest string«*, but just that the `.` *after* `item 8` is matched as few times as possible until you encounter `Financial ...`. This ensures that you pick the first `Financial ...`, but does *not* ensure that you pick the last `item 8`.

The starting point of the search for `Financial ...` is unaffected by the `?` modifier. You could say `item 8` is greedy, since it will match the first `item 8` in your string as long as there is a `Financial ...` after that.

To get the shortest match, you can ensure that `item 8` never occurs inside the matched part of `.*?`.

```
item 8((?!item 8).)*?Financial Statements and Supplementary Data
```

Comment: Your right, i misunderstood. I will try this out see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

The most up to date regex package (not re) in Python has an overlap option so i can do this...

```
import regex as re
re.findall(pattern_8, temp, re.IGNORECASE, overlapped=True)
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(pattern_8, temp,re.IGNORECASE, overlapped=True)]
Out[161]: [(0, 77), (23, 77)]
```

Using the overlapped function gives me both matches very quickly.